# Recurrence $T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + \Theta(\log_2\log_2n) $

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, data-structure

I want to solve the recurrence with iterative Method, but I don't know how to finish it.
This is the last thing I solved, but how can I continue?

$$T(n) = T(n^{1/2^i}) + \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\log_2\log_2n} n^{1/2^i}.\Theta(\log_2\log_2) $$
where $$k = \log_2\log_2n$$

Answer (score 1):

From

$$
T(n) = T\left(\sqrt n\right)+\Theta\left(\log_2(\log_2 n)\right)
$$

with $z = \log_2 n$ we have

$$
\mathbb T(z)=\mathbb T(z/2)+\Theta(\log_2 z)
$$

and now with $u = \log_2 z$

$$
\mathcal T(u)=\mathcal T(u-1) + \Theta(u)
$$

so

$$
\mathcal T(u) = C_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{u}\Theta(k)
$$

now $\mathcal T(u)\rightarrow \mathbb T(z)\rightarrow T(n)$

hence

$$
T(n) =  C_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{\log_2(\log_2 n)}\Theta(k)
$$